# want to make text size 15% bigger in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, resolution

The text in my 17 inche secreen is small so I changed it to 125% (medium) but I also did not like that because it is now a bit big in the size. How can I make it something like 115%? because there are only 3 options avaiable (default - medium - larger) ad I don't know how to make it 115%.

Comment: Could it be a registry setting that could be modified?  ie. find the reg setting and change 125% to 115%?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to that window where you adjust to 125%/150%, in the left panel, you will see `Set custom text size (DPI)`, click and adjust, done.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. If it interests anyone, there's extended instructions with screenshots [on this Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller). Just go down and expand the *To create a custom DPI scale* section.

Comment: @Bob, yes, that's better explained, for everyone :)